# How to register an Android custom view as an observer

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern, android-sensors

I have a class *OrientationSensor* implementing SensorEventListener that I've made **Observable**.

I have a custom control *OrientationPointer* extending ImageView and implementing **Observer** which needs to respond to updates from *OrientationSensor*. Instances of *OrientationPointer* are created via XML layout.

I don't want *OrientationPointer* to implement SensorEventListener as there will be several instances in the same Activity.

In plain Java I'd just add an Observable parameter to the *OrientationPointer* constructor.

In Android it looks like I will have to instantiate *OrientationPointer* in code instead of XML so I can call a custom constructor, or somehow get the *OrientationSensor* during onFinishInflate().

Does either option seem reasonable, or is there a better way of achieving this while maintaining the separation of SensorListener and View?